# Can RGB values be negative?

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to draw a picture using `glVertex`. And here is my code:

```
struct Pixel{
    GLbyte R, G, B;
};

 GLbyte * originalData = NULL;

 . . . 

 originalData = (GLbyte *)malloc(IMAGE_SIZE);
 fread(originalData, IMAGE_SIZE, 1, file);
  for (int n = 0; n < 256 * 256; n++){
        pixels[n].R = data[n * 3 + 0];
        pixels[n].G = data[n * 3 + 1];
        pixels[n].B = data[n * 3 + 2];

        if (pixels[n].R < (GLbyte)0) std::cerr << "??" << std::endl;
    }
```

And the Display Function:

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
unsigned int i = 0;
for (unsigned row = 0; row < iWidth; row++){
    for (unsigned col = 0; col < iHeight; col++){
        glColor3b(pixels[i].R, pixels[i].G, pixels[i].B);
        glVertex3f(row,col,0.0f);
        i++;
    }
}
glEnd();
```

When I'm using `glDrawPixels(256, 256, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, originalData);` Everything is OK, but Colors get mixed up when I'm using my method.

Can RGB values be negative? when I use

```
glColor3b(abs(pixels[i].R), abs(pixels[i].G), abs(pixels[i].B));
```

my output looks better(but again some colors get mixed up).

**NOTE1:** I'm trying to rasterize a `.raw` file that I created with Photoshop

**NOTE2:** I know my method is dummy, but I'm experimenting things

Comment: Since you're using `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` for `glDrawPixels` (which you say looks ok?), shouldn't you be using `GLubyte` and `glColor3ub` in your own method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `glColor3b` which interprets the arguments as *signed* bytes. So any color value >= 128 will be interpreted as negative - and clamped to 0 later in the pipeline (assuming reasonable defaults).

Since you want to use the full range 0-255, just use `glColor3ub` and use the type `GLubyte` which is for *unsigned* bytes.